# Error when running v.krige

Tags: r, grass-7.0

I've been trying to get v.krige to run in the Grass7 command line, however, when I do so I get the following error:

```
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'rgrass7', details:
call: if (class(t0) != "try-error" && is.character(t0) && nchar(t0) >
error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
ERROR: R package(s) rgrass7 missing. Install it/them and re-run v.krige.
```

However, when I check in R what libraries are installed I clearly show that rgrass7 is installed.

As a note I get a very similar error if I open R inside Grass7 using the following commands:

```
> library(rgrass7)
Loading required package: sp
Loading required package: XML
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'rgrass7', details:
call: if (class(t0) != "try-error" && is.character(t0) && nchar(t0) >
error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rgrass7'
```

So it appears R inside of Grass7 isn't able to load this module, but if I run the same command inside the RGui, I get this:

```
> library(rgrass7)
Loading required package: sp
Loading required package: XML
GRASS GIS interface loaded with GRASS version: (GRASS not running)
```

Anyone know what might be going on and how I can get v.krige to work?

Comment: Could it be you are using two distinct R-setups? One inside grass, one "inside" your RGui. If so you may need to install rgrass7 in the grass-context as well.

Comment: On windows 7 with the OSGeo4W64 installation of GRASS 7, I found that having the environment variable `GRASS_ADDON_BASE` set to `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.0.4\bin` caused this error. I had to remove it - specifying addon_base in initGRASS wasn't enough to fix the issue. That's not really a problem, one just has to remember to set it temporarily when installing addons.

Comment: After a ton of digging, this appears to be this bug: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/commits/a1a8364e9a82